# Is it possible to delete specific push notifications from the Notification Center?

Tags: ios

I'd like to be able to delete specific delivered push notifications from the Notification Center.

`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()` obviously can't be used as it will delete everything.

`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers)` is ok for a local notification, where you can set the identifier when you create and post the notification.
However there appears to be no way of setting the identifier for a push notification, nor if you implement a notification service extension does there appear to be either a way of setting the identifier in there before the push is delivered, nor any way of obtaining whatever internal identifier the OS has assigned.

Is there therefore actually anyway of deleting specific push notifications from the Notification Center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation you can remove a specific notification from the notification center using [removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649500-removedeliverednotifications) method.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [yourNotificationIdentifier])
```

You can specify an identifier for the remote notification as well, as per the documentation of [identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649634-identifier):

> For remote notifications, it is set to the value of the
>   apns-collapse-id key that you specified in the APNs request header
>   when generating the remote notification. If no value is set, the
>   system automatically assigns an identifier.